# Crashing the App when using CGMutablePathRef in only device while drawing Graph

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios4, core-graphics

```
    CGMutablePathRef smoothedCGPath = CreateSmoothedBezierPathFromPath(self.CGPath, tension);
```

When i call the method

```
CreateSmoothedBezierPathFromPath(self.CGPath, tension);

CGMutablePathRef CreateSmoothedBezierPathFromPath( CGPathRef path, CGFloat tention)
{
    //convert path to 2 arrays of CGFloats
    struct dataPointer my_dataPointer; //this struct will hold the 2 indexes of the CGpath
    my_dataPointer.numberOfPoints = 0;
    my_dataPointer.isClosed = NO;
    CGPathApply(path, &my_dataPointer, savePathToArraysApplierFunc);

//the arrays where the control points will be stored
CGFloat controlPoints_x[2*_max_points];
CGFloat controlPoints_y[2*_max_points];

calculateBezierControlPoints(  controlPoints_x, controlPoints_y, my_dataPointer.indexx , my_dataPointer.indexy, my_dataPointer.isClosed, my_dataPointer.numberOfPoints, tention);

//the final CGpath constisting of original points and computed control points
CGMutablePathRef bezierPath = CGPathCreateMutable();

for (int i = 0; i<my_dataPointer.numberOfPoints + (int) my_dataPointer.isClosed; i++) 
{
    if(i==0)
        CGPathMoveToPoint(bezierPath, nil, my_dataPointer.indexx[0], my_dataPointer.indexy[0]);
    else if (i==my_dataPointer.numberOfPoints) //this happens when the path is closed
        CGPathAddCurveToPoint(bezierPath, nil, controlPoints_x[i*2-2], controlPoints_y[i*2-2], controlPoints_x[i*2-1], controlPoints_y[i*2-1],my_dataPointer.indexx[0], my_dataPointer.indexy[0]);
    else
        CGPathAddCurveToPoint(bezierPath, nil, controlPoints_x[i*2-2], controlPoints_y[i*2-2], controlPoints_x[i*2-1], controlPoints_y[i*2-1],my_dataPointer.indexx[i], my_dataPointer.indexy[i]);
}
if(my_dataPointer.isClosed)
    CGPathCloseSubpath(bezierPath);

return bezierPath;
```

}

In the above method , return bezierPath is crashing the App in device, it is crashing with no crash reason. It works fine in simulator.

Comment: What do you mean "it is crashing with no crash reason"? What does the crash log look like? How do you know it's crashing in the above function?

Comment: When i debug with device, app is crashing when it reaches to the last line return bezierPath; It doesn't print crash reason in the console.

Comment: What does the debugger show? Usually it will stop on the line in question and will display text in the bar that highlights that line that says something like "EXEC_BAD_ACCESS" or some other message. Also, do you have "break on C++ Exceptions" or "Break on Objective-C Exceptions"?

Comment: I checked in device logs, it is Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Comment: Usually an abort is caused by either a call to `assert()` or `exit()`. Sometimes that can happen in a library call, but not usually. Can you post the stack trace for thread 0?

Comment: Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x3ab7e350 0x3ab6d000 + 70480
1   libsystem_c.dylib              0x3aaf511e 0x3aac6000 + 192798
2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x3ab319f2 0x3aac6000 + 440818
3   libsystem_c.dylib              0x3ab3203e 0x3aac6000 + 442430
4   ChildHealthStory               0x0012106c 0x5a000 + 815212
5   ChildHealthStory               0x00121088 0x5a000 + 815240
6   ChildHealthStory               0x00125146 0x5a000 + 831814

Comment: 7   ChildHealthStory               0x00123ffe 0x5a000 + 827390
8   QuartzCore                     0x3455c1ae 0x3454e000 + 57774
9   QuartzCore                     0x3455b910 0x3454e000 + 55568
10  QuartzCore                     0x34552936 0x3454e000 + 18742
11  QuartzCore                     0x34552860 0x3454e000 + 18528
12  QuartzCore                     0x3455223e 0x3454e000 + 16958
13  QuartzCore                     0x3455204c 0x3454e000 + 16460
14  QuartzCore                     0x34551eac 0x3454e000 + 16044
15  CoreFoundation                 0x329716ca 0x328da000 + 620234

Comment: 16  CoreFoundation                 0x3296f9bc 0x328da000 + 612796
17  CoreFoundation                 0x3296fd12 0x328da000 + 613650
18  CoreFoundation                 0x328e2eb8 0x328da000 + 36536
19  CoreFoundation                 0x328e2d44 0x328da000 + 36164
20  GraphicsServices               0x364aa2e6 0x364a5000 + 21222
21  UIKit                          0x347f82fc 0x347a1000 + 357116
22  ChildHealthStory               0x00075bf2 0x5a000 + 113650
23  libdyld.dylib                  0x3aab7b1c 0x3aab6000 + 6940

Comment: Because you don't have symbols in the stack trace, it's impossible to say the exact function you called that crashed, but the trace indicates that something inside the "ChildHealthStory" library called into the standard C Library, and that function crashed. Beyond that, there's not much anyone can tell you without symbols.

Comment: Can you tell me how can i get symbols?  If i comment the for loop in the above code then it is not crashing. We got these methods from a sample code which is working fine. Sample code path : https://github.com/Petrakeas/outlineDEMO

Comment: The same code works fine in simulator, if the build configuration is debug mode it is working fine in device too. If the build configuration is release mode then only we are facing the crash.